# option not get selected in react js

Tags: reactjs, select

when I am selecting option then it is showing countries but not get selected.

this is my code-

```
 <form method='POST' autoComplete="off">
<div className="form">
<div className="form-body">
    <div className="country" >
        <label className="form__label" htmlFor="country">Country </label>
        <Select options={options} value={user.country} onChange = {getUserData}  />
        
    </div>
    {errors.country?<p className='text-center text-danger'>{errors.country}</p>: ("")}     
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <button type="submit" onClick={postData} class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Register</button>
</div>
```

this is getUserData function-

```
     const getUserData = (event) => {
    name=event.target.name;
    value=event.target.value;

    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
    console.log(user);
};
```

Comment: You never change `user.country`

Comment: When you debug, what are the values of `name` and `value` in the `getUserData` function?

Comment: name and value will store country name